# Como Mandar Sort viu URL em query nativa de paginação?

Tags: java, classificação, paginação, spring-data

A estrutura abaixo funciona perfeitamente, mas quando mando após os dados de entrada e paginação o comando sort ele da erro de Sql, o que preciso colocar na query para aceitar o sort pelo campo que eu quiser ?

Estou mandando esses dados via URL: `dadosEntrada?page=0&size=10&sort=campoDoSort`

```
@Query(value = "select i.* " + "from tabela1 r  "
+ "join tabela2 ri on ri.chavetabela2 = r.chavetabela1  "
+ "join tabela3 i on i.chavetabela3 = ri.chavetabela2 "
+ "where r.campo1 = ?1 or i.campo2 = ?2 /*#pageable*/ ",
 countQuery = "SELECT count(*) "
+ "from tabela1 r  "
+ "join tabela2 ri on ri.chavetabela2 = r.chavetabela1  "
+ "join tabela3 i on i.chavetabela3 = ri.chavetabela2 "
+ "where r.campo1 = ?1 or i.campo2 = ?2  ",
   nativeQuery = true)
public Page<ClasseModeloTabela> testePaginacaoQueryJoin(Long campo1, Long campo2, Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: É oracle o banco? Qual é o erro de SQL? Consegue incluir o SQL gerado em ambos casos? Veja se algo como `where r.campo1 = ?1 or i.campo2 = ?2 ORDER BY /*#pageable*/` não gera o trecho de paginação e ordenação corretamente.

Comment: sim o banco é Oracle, tentei o comando (ORDER BY /*#pageable*/), mas ele da erro SQLgrammarException

Comment: Se souber de alguma novidade me posta ai, já tentei de tudo mas ainda não achei a resposta.